External SSD storage devices are not recognized by Ubuntu 22.04
First off, this problem has nothing to do with suggested similar questions involving booting from or onto an SSD.  My issue is that certain external USB storage devices are not recognized by my computer.
I have both an external Seagate SSD and an external Crucial SSD storage device for backing up files, and my Dell laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 will not recognize either one.  Both of these devices have been previously used only on my Linux Mint 21 and Linux Mint 21.3 Edge computers where they work flawlessly.
This Ubuntu Dell laptop has no problem recognizing USB thumbdrives, in both FAT and NTFS formats.  However external SSD devices are another matter.
Things I have tried:

ls /dev/ | grep sd (with & without the device connected) and neither returned any inputs.
I also tried entering something suggested elsewhere that I can't find now or remember but part of the command was blkid.  This returned these 2 responses.

without the device connected:
crowbait@crowbait-Precision-5480:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for crowbait: 
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="UBUNTU" UUID="ff7f2f2d-908f-42a7-acb2-e5becc7e264e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1a8c95e1-5ef4-4e93-b17f-c12659232b8b"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="3059-E301" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="0bd75690-25f1-44d8-a26d-b83414c7fa42"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="OS" UUID="6287-A79D" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b6943e70-d5ef-4173-9c15-938632d41679"
/dev/loop27p1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2024-05-09-19-52-32-00" LABEL="Dell jellyfish-torchic X77.1" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="0173fd30-760e-4991-a70e-1a419670f31f"
/dev/loop27p2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="8D6C-A9F8" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2" PARTUUID="0173fd30-760e-4991-a70d-1a419670f31f"
/dev/loop27p3: PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="0173fd30-760e-4991-a70c-1a419670f31f"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
crowbait@crowbait-Precision-5480:~$ 

and with device connected:
crowbait@crowbait-Precision-5480:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for crowbait: 
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="UBUNTU" UUID="ff7f2f2d-908f-42a7-acb2-e5becc7e264e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1a8c95e1-5ef4-4e93-b17f-c12659232b8b"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="3059-E301" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="0bd75690-25f1-44d8-a26d-b83414c7fa42"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="OS" UUID="6287-A79D" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b6943e70-d5ef-4173-9c15-938632d41679"
/dev/loop27p1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2024-05-09-19-52-32-00" LABEL="Dell jellyfish-torchic X77.1" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="0173fd30-760e-4991-a70e-1a419670f31f"
/dev/loop27p2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="8D6C-A9F8" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2" PARTUUID="0173fd30-760e-4991-a70d-1a419670f31f"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop27p3: PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="0173fd30-760e-4991-a70c-1a419670f31f"
crowbait@crowbait-Precision-5480:~$ 

I am not familiar with use of the terminal, so I can't interpret these responses.
I'd be grateful for any solutions to this problem.
OK lsblk -ape7 without either drive gives me this:
crowbait@crowbait-Precision-5480:~$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/nvme0n1     259:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
├─/dev/nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  940M  0 part /boot/efi
├─/dev/nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   12G  0 part
└─/dev/nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  3.7T  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
and with the Crucial Drive, this:
crowbait@crowbait-Precision-5480:~$ lsblk -ape7
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/nvme0n1     259:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
├─/dev/nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  940M  0 part /boot/efi
├─/dev/nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   12G  0 part
└─/dev/nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  3.7T  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
/
Again I have no idea what this means, except it looks like the same info with the drive as without it.  I guess it won't be the end of the world if I can't get Ubuntu to recognize these storage devices, since I can back them up from my Linux Mint laptops.

Maybe your Dell doesn't supply enough power via the USB port. Try adding an external power supply to the external enclosure or even a "Y" connector to get power from two USB ports.

If NTFS are they used with Windows? And is Windows fast startup off? Windows turns it back on with some updates.

The only difference between those two lists is that line 8 has moved to line 33 ( /dev/loop27p3 )  Used diff to find that - now try lsblk -ape7 with and without the drives.

In addition to lrunning sblk with the -e which will exclude the loops which are just your snaps also run this: lsusb or with more details: lsusb -vvv

Thanks for the replies/suggestions.  Neither SSD has ever been used with Windows, only on Mint where they work fine.  The Crucial device is exFAT and its partition type is listed as Microsoft Reserved.  It has 1.0 TB of storage.  The Seagate one is also exFAT and partition type is NTFS/exFAT/HPFS and has 500 GB storage.
